# Discord oauth2 giving me a error in the code

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to set up an oauth2 with discord and keep getting in this error:
cannot find module '../utils'
its needed for the catchAsync function.

Tutorial that I used: https://medium.com/@orels1/using-discord-oauth2-a-simple-guide-and-an-example-nodejs-app-71a9e032770

How exactly can I fix it now?

Comment: Could you give us some context? Maybe add some of **your** code to the question?

Comment: the code is nearly the same, i only changed the discord link but here
https://pastebin.com/q6EkR4v0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're requiring either the [utils package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utils#api), or a `utils.js` file in the same folder as your code.

Looking at the GitHub repository at the end of the post you linked, they seem to have [a `utils.js` file](https://github.com/orels1/discord-token-generator/blob/master/utils.js). Adding that file to your folder should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! i didn't saw it that there is a github copy for it

Comment: Do you maybe know how to fix this porblem? https://prnt.sc/skr3ul don't know what issue is causing this

Comment: Ok i got it to work, but i get a undefined token, sorry for the many comments, Science i can't find a edit button...